# Xcode Picker View Not Working

Tags: xcode, uipickerview

I am trying to make a picker view with three places appear on my app. Here is the code I have so far:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var BillAmount: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var PercentTip: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var SalesTax: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var TipAmount: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TotalAmount: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var TaxAmount: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var PlacePicker: UIPickerView!

var placeArray = ["Atlanta","Boston","New York City"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    PlacePicker.delegate = self
    PlacePicker.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func btnCalPress(sender: AnyObject) {
    let tipPer = Double(PercentTip.text!)! / 100
    let billAmt = Double(BillAmount.text!)
    let salesTax = Double(SalesTax.text!)! / 100

    let tipAmt = Double(billAmt! * tipPer)
    let taxAmt = Double(billAmt! * salesTax)
    let totalAmt = tipAmt + taxAmt + billAmt!

    let tipAmountFormat = round(tipAmt * 100) / 100
    let taxAmountFormat = round(taxAmt * 100) / 100
    let totalPayFormat = round(totalAmt * 100) / 100

    TipAmount.text = "Tip: $\(tipAmountFormat)"
    TaxAmount.text = "Tax: $\(taxAmountFormat)"
    TotalAmount.text = "Total: $\(totalPayFormat)"
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return placeArray[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return placeArray.count
}

func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
```

}

It is a tip calculator, and I want the user to pick what city they are in. When I run it, it says it was successful, but then I get this error:

[image]

I know its something about the connection from my storyboard, but I have redone that already and I am pretty sure I did it correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check the connection of `ViewController` from your storyboard. One of its connection is linked to a var named `PickerView` when I guess it should be to one named `PlacePicker`.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Where do I check this? I am new to Xcode